# Gnome problem with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, display, gui, vnc

I got an install of 14.04 Server on my VPS.  I then installed the GUI with: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, then installed VNC with vnc4server.

Now I have this really, bugged gray screen instead of the normal Ubuntu UI.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: It looks very much like a single window, larger than the size of your current screen.  Can you try pressing alt+space to see if the context menu allowing resize of that window pops up?

Comment: That seems to do nothing at all, a point I can't quite show with that screenshot, is that my cursor is an "X". Also, you may notice, that I have no minimize, maximize or close buttons on an open window. Another image: http://i.imgur.com/Cn90gWF.png

Comment: So, what's behind the big grey window?  I notice that it has min-max-close buttons, although they are in the top-right corner.

Comment: those min-max buttons are VNC Viewer's, I cannot interact with the grey screen in any way :/